# problem of the sample PHP/AJAX in W3school

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read a example of PHP/AJAX in
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
```

Why there is a need to declare database twice. first, my_db in mysqli_connect, then ajax_demon in mysqli_select_db, I can't do the effect of ajax after copied all codes.

Comment: Please don't follow w3schools for tutorials on PHP. They are providing terrible code examples and really bad advice. Here are some good articles: https://phpdelusions.net/

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to connect to the server with the `my_db` database, never use it, then immediately switch to the `ajax_demo` database.

This is just W3Schools being of their usual low quality (as is the massive [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) security hole on the first line after `mysqli_select_db`)